# How to best escape SQL in Saxon

Tags: saxon

What is the best way to escape SQL in Saxon?  Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<xsl:variable name="sql-value" select="$field-value => org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql()"/>
```

If so, would I just need to include this jar file?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Saxon-PE or -EE you can make calls directly from XPath expressions to Java methods. These are referred to as "reflexive extension functions" and are described at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!extensibility/extension-functions-J/reflexive-functions

I haven't managed to track down the spec of `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql()` but if it's a simple static method taking a string argument and returning a string result then you can call it as:

```
select="$field-value => Q{java:org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils}escapeSql()"/>
```

If you want to do this with the open-source Saxon-HE then you'll need to jump through a few more hoops and write some Java wrapper code: all is explained at

https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!extensibility/extension-functions-J/ext-simple-J